# Problem in toString function in java (works with local variable)

Tags: java

i have a class in a java program where i am using a toString function to retrieve data. the toString checks a private function in the same class which returns a int value, for displaying different types of return messages.~

The problem is that if i use a local variable in the string function every turns out good, but if i check in the if statements directlly the private function, this function doesnt return any value.

```
private int computerTryHorizontalPlay() {

        int repeatedMyValueCount = 0;
        int repeatedYourValueCount = 0;
        int[] myPositions = new int[3];
        int[] yourPositions = new int[3];

        for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
            int repeatedMyValue = 0;
            int repeatedYourValue = 0;
            int emptyFields = 0;
            int[] emptyPosition = new int[2];
            for (int b = 0; b < 3; b++) {
                if (jogoGalo[a][b] == 'X') {
                    repeatedMyValue++;
                } else if (jogoGalo[a][b] == 'O') {
                    repeatedYourValue++;
                }
                if (jogoGalo[a][b] == '-') {
                    emptyPosition[0] = a;
                    emptyPosition[1] = b;
                    emptyFields++;
                }
            }

            if (repeatedMyValue == 3 || repeatedYourValue == 3) {
                return 3;
            } else {
                if (emptyFields == 1) {
                    if (repeatedMyValue == 2) {
                        repeatedMyValueCount++;
                        myPositions[repeatedMyValueCount - 1] = emptyPosition[0];
                        myPositions[repeatedMyValueCount] = emptyPosition[1];
                    } else if (repeatedYourValue == 2) {
                        repeatedYourValueCount++;
                        yourPositions[repeatedYourValueCount - 1] = emptyPosition[0];
                        yourPositions[repeatedYourValueCount] = emptyPosition[1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (repeatedMyValueCount > 0) {
            jogoGalo[myPositions[0]][myPositions[1]] = 'X';
            return 2;
        } else if (repeatedYourValueCount > 0) {
            jogoGalo[yourPositions[0]][yourPositions[1]] = 'X';
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

This doesn´t work!

```
    public String toString() {
        if(computerTryHorizontalPlay() == 3) {
            return "The game has already ended!";
        }
        else if(computerTryHorizontalPlay() == 2) {
            return "Computer won!";
        }
        else if(computerTryHorizontalPlay() == 1) {
            return "Computer defendeu!";
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This works!

```
public String toString() {

        int horizontalFunctionValue = computerTryHorizontalPlay();

        if(horizontalFunctionValue == 3) {
            return "The game has already ended!";
        }
        else if(horizontalFunctionValue == 2) {
            return "Computer won!";
        }
        else if(horizontalFunctionValue == 1) {
            return "Computer defendeu!";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Think about how many times `computerTryHorizontalPlay` is being called in each case.

Comment: You're not-working version is calling `computerTryHorizontalPlay()` multiple times. The first time alters the data it's looking at so it can give a different result the next time.

Comment: This would be a good use of a Switch, rather than multiple if-else if-else statement, regardless why this isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toString()` *must* be a read-only method, i.e. it is not allowed to have side-effects like changing the state of the object. Since `computerTryHorizontalPlay()` is a state-changing method, you are not allowed to call it from `toString()`.

Since the only state-change happens in the last `if` statement, you can change the code to not execute the play when called from `toString()`, like this:

```
private int computerTryHorizontalPlay() {
    return computerTryHorizontalPlay(true);
}

private int computerTryHorizontalPlay(boolean doMove) {

    // lots of code here

    if (repeatedMyValueCount > 0) {
        if (doMove)
            jogoGalo[myPositions[0]][myPositions[1]] = 'X';
        return 2;
    } else if (repeatedYourValueCount > 0) {
        if (doMove)
            jogoGalo[yourPositions[0]][yourPositions[1]] = 'X';
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

public String toString() {
    if(computerTryHorizontalPlay(false) == 3) {
        return "The game has already ended!";
    }
    else if(computerTryHorizontalPlay(false) == 2) {
        return "Computer won!";
    }
    else if(computerTryHorizontalPlay(false) == 1) {
        return "Computer defeated!";
    }
    return null;
}
```